# StartUp Applications not scaled on hidpi display

Tags: 18.04, startup-applications, hdpi

I run Ubuntu 18.04 with Gnome on a 4k hidpi monitor with 200% scale factor. If I manually run applications (e.g. Wavebox, Telegram Desktop, KeePassXC, ...) they start scaled properly and everything is fine.
However, if I add them to the startup applications, when I start the system, they start without scaling and are impossible to use. When I close the apps and restart them, they are scaled.

How do I run an app at startup with the proper scaling?

Comment: same problem here, couldn't accept @markus-helin's answer as it's a workaround and not a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and what solve the problem for me was to startup the application with a few seconds delay.

create a bash script and add the following

```
#!/bin/sh
sleep 5
/usr/bin/conky
```

save the file and run chmod +x conky.sh

next open up gnome startup application or edit: ~/.config/autostart/conky.desktop and update the Exec/Command to:
/home/youruser/conky.sh

(Just replace conky with the application you are using)
now try logout and back in again and hopefully it should work
if it doesent work you can try increase the sleep/delay to 10 seconds.